# java.sql executing different statements in one batch

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 2 different sql statements that need to be be executed together. Is there a way to execute them both in one batch?

Bellow is an example of what I tried but it doesn't seem to work as it adds the string of index 1 in ''

```
        pstm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ? values(?,?,?)");
        pstm.setString(1, "db.table1(name1, status, name2)");
        pstm.setString(2, n1);
        pstm.setBoolean(3, true);
        pstm.setString(4, n2);
        pstm.addBatch();
        
        pstm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ? values(?,?,?)");
        pstm.setString(1, "db.table2(name1, status, name2)");
        pstm.setString(2, n1);
        pstm.setBoolean(3, true);
        pstm.setString(4, n2);
        pstm.addBatch();
```

Comment: you can use prepared statements only for replacement of data not column names or table names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works. The rollback covers both statements so it is a proper transaction:

```
    pstm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 
        db.table1(name1, status, name2) values(?,?,?)");
    pstm.setString(1, n1);
    pstm.setBoolean(2, true);
    pstm.setString(3, n2);
    pstm.addBatch();
    
    pstm2 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 
        db.table2(name1, status, name2) values(?,?,?)");
    pstm2.setString(1, n1);
    pstm2.setBoolean(2, true);
    pstm2.setString(3, n2);
    pstm2.addBatch();

    try{
        pstm1.executeBatch();
        pstm2.executeBatch();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
```